# How to list next 24 months' start dates with python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

Please tell me how I can list next 24 months' start dates with python,

such as:

```
01May2014
01June2014
.
.
.
01Aug2015
```

and so on

I tried:

```
import datetime

this_month_start = datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=1)

for i in xrange(24):
    print  (this_month_start + i*datetime.timedelta(40)).replace(day=1)
```

But it skips some months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increment the month value; I used `datetime.date()` types here as that's more than enough:

```
current = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)

for i in xrange(24):
    new_month = current.month % 12 + 1
    new_year = current.year + current.month // 12
    current = current.replace(month=new_month, year=new_year)
    print current
```

The new month calculation picks the next month based on the last calculated month, and the year is incremented every time the previous month reached December.

By manipulating a `current` object, you simplify the calculations; you can do it with `i` as an offset as well, but the calculation gets a little more complicated.

It'll work with `datetime.datetime()` too.

Comment: It took me some time to realize that `current.month // 12 == (current.month == 12)`

Answer (score 1):

To simplify arithmetics, try/except could be used:

```
from datetime import date

current = date.today().replace(day=1)
for _ in range(24):
    try:
        current = current.replace(month=current.month + 1)
    except ValueError: # new year
        current = current.replace(month=1, year=current.year + 1)
    print(current.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
```